# What is CID field created by Create Random points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, random

In ArcGIS the result of [Create Random Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002r000000) tool when using a feature class to constrain the extents has an attribute called `CID`. What do the values in this field represent?

[image: pic of attribute table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CID values represent the FIDs of the features in which the random points were generated.